# Form with ruby on rails is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are trying to make a website for a restaurant using Ruby on Rails.

When we try to submit a form we are getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Home#bookmytable
```

What could be the problem?

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
    def menu
    end
    def bookmytable
        @table = Table.new
    end
    def create
        @table = Table.new table_params
        if @table.save
        else
            render index
        end
    end
    private
        def table_params
           params.require(:table).permit(:name, :emailID , :nop , :datee , :timee , :message)
        end
end
```

**bookmytable.html.erb**

```
<h1>Book my table</h1>

<p><%= form_for :table,url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>

    Username <%= f.text_field :name %> <br />

    Email ID <%= f.text_field :emailID %><br/>

    No of people <%= options_for_select(:nop , [['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three' , 3] , ['Four' , 4] ], 1 ) %><br/>

    Date <%= f.text_field :datee %>

    Time <%= options_for_select(:timee , [[ '08:00',1 ], ['08:30' , 2], ['09:00' , 3], ['09:30' , 4], ['10:00' , 5], ['10:30' , 6],  ['12:30' , 7], ['13:00' , 8], ['13:30' , 9], ['14:00' , 10], ['14:30' , 11], ['18:00' , 12], ['18:30' , 13], ['19:00' , 14], ['19:30' , 15], ['20:00' , 16], ['20:30' , 17], ['21:00' , 18], ['21:30' , 19], ['22:00' , 20], ['22:30' , 21]], 1) %> </br>

    Message to restaurant <%= f.text_area :message %>

    <%= f.submit "Book my table" %>

<% end %></p>
```

Comment: Please post the content of `app/controllers/home_controller.rb`.

Comment: I am sure you are missing the method of `permit` section of ` mass assignment ` in your controller

Comment: Copy and paste just your `create` action of your `HomeController`

Comment: Please consider moving the code from pastebin to the body of the question.

Comment: Unbalanced `end`s is the problem. If you formatted your code correctly, it would've been obvious.

Comment: Yes. Removed an end. Now it says syntax error in create in home_controller. Can you help me with that. I am not sure what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @kalyanamrajashree: start with indenting the code properly, not removing random keywords.

Comment: Hint: `if` requires an `end` too. Use an editor which highlights counterparts of current symbol (thus showing which bracket is closed by this one and which thing exactly is closed by this `end`)

Comment: I have made changes suggested and errors found. Still the problem is with the form. Is there any mistake in bookmytable.html.erb ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
    @table = Table.new table_params
    if @table.save
    else
        render index
    ***end***
end
```

You're missing an end after the render line. Ruby syntax requires an `end` keyword to end the if statement

Comment: I added it. Now I see NoMethodError in Home#bookmytable error. What could be wrong in bookmytable ? I have put the code bookmytable.html.erb

Comment: Read the line number where the error is. Try to use puts statements intelligently. Basic debugging stuff. Also if you have a new problem, you should ask another question rather than editing your previous post and changing the question.

Comment: Sure. I will put another question if I still cant solve it.